# How to merge multiple rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran into some problems while structuring my database, and I will ask two questions.

First question: below table needs to be merged by the same IDs

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║     ║       ║
 ║  0  ║       ║ 11  ║       ║
 ║  0  ║       ║     ║   6   ║
 ║  1  ║ Dave  ║     ║       ║
 ║  1  ║       ║ 12  ║       ║
 ║  1  ║       ║     ║   7   ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

so it should look like this;

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║ 11  ║   6   ║
 ║  0  ║ Dave  ║ 12  ║   7   ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

NOTE: id* is not AUTO_INCREMENT

---

Second question: You probably think that the former database structure is poor. The good thing is, I haven't created the database yet and I have been looking for a solution to add data to an existing row without removing old information, but if there is no old information, it would create a new row. Thanks in advance.

### Second question explained

Virgin table

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║     ║       ║     ║       ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

*some SQL statement*

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║     ║       ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

*the same SQL statement with different parameters*

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║     ║       ║
 ║  1  ║ Dave  ║     ║       ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

*another SQL statement*

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║     ║       ║
 ║  1  ║ Dave  ║ 12  ║       ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

*another SQL statement*

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║ age ║ grade ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║ John  ║     ║   6   ║
 ║  1  ║ Dave  ║ 12  ║       ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to apply an aggregate function to all the columns and then `GROUP BY id`:

```
select id,
  max(name) name,
  max(age) age,
  max(grade) grade
from yourtable
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b31/1)

As far as the DB structure, the only issue that I see is that you are inserting multiple records for the same user. You should be using an `UPDATE` statement to use the values instead of inserting.

It sounds like you want to use the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function in MySQL ([here is a tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx)).

So the query would be similar to this:

```
REPLACE 
  INTO yourtable (`id`, `name`, `age`, `grade`) 
  VALUES (0, 'john', 11, null);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0637/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, what about my databate structure?

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?  Seriously I get a DV but the other answer doesn't

Comment: @TheConjuring I don't understand your question about the database structure what are you asking?

Comment: Like, I haven't got these entries yet. I'm pretty sure that MySQL has something like INSERT OR REPLACE, but I don't know if it's the thing I'm asking for. I'll explain more on the OP in a few seconds.

Comment: @TheConjuring if you're trying to ask two different questions, please do so by asking two different questions rather than splintering this one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand only doing this because I don't want to fall into the XY problem.

Comment: @TheConjuring You might want to review the `REPLACE` syntax for MySQL -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: @TheConjuring sorry, not familiar with the XY problem I guess.

Comment: @TheConjuring I updated my answer to include some details about the `REPLACE` function in MySQL

Answer (score 5):

You could group by `id`, and use any aggregate function to pick the non-null row.  This example uses `max`, but `min` would work too:

```
select  id
,       max(name) as name
,       max(age) as age
,       max(grade) as grade
from    YourTable
group by
        id
```